# How do I write a callback to an immediately invoked function in a loop?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have a loop to gather all elements of a certain class and insert something into that element.

```
var node;
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
for(var i = 1; i <= nodes.length; ++i) {
  function () {
    var element = document.creatElement('script');
    node = document.getElementById('my-node' + i);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(element, node);
  })();
}
```

I have some code that I need to make a callback to this because it uses the id of `node` but when I run that code it only runs on the last element of the array even if I call it in the for loop. Basically what I need is to keep the value of the node variable and use it in a callback function each pass through the loop.

If I understand javascript correctly, this means I need a callback, but I dont know how to write one for an immediately invoked function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Teemu,  this is exactly what i needed.  and a much better way to word the question!

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand exactly what you want, but if you want to keep the value you need to pass it to the function due the closure :

```
 var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
  for(i=1; i<=nodes.length; ++i){
    function(valueofI){
    var element = document.creatElement('script');
    node = document.getElementById('my-node'+valueofI);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(element, node);
  })(i);
}
```

I hope it is what you need.

Comment: i need to keep value of node actually but i think this will actually do well enough as an example